# Markov Chain Derivation question

Tags: probability, probability-theory, markov-chains, markov-process

[This page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markov_chain#Discrete-time_Markov_chain) defines the Markov Property as the following.  Does anyone how form (b) becomes (c)?  Is it due to $(X_{n-1} = i_{n-1}) \subset (X_{n-1} = i_{n-1}) \cap ... \cap (X_0 = i_0)$?  Is it due to independence of the conditional events?

a)
$$
\mathbb{P}(X_0 = i_0, X_1 = i_1, X_2 = i_2, ..., X_n = i+n)
$$
b)

$$
= \mathbb{P}(X_0 = i_0) \mathbb{P}(X_1 = i_1 | X_0 = i_0) \mathbb{P}(X_2 = i_2 | X_1 = i_1, X_0 = i_0) ... \mathbb{P}(X_n = i_n | X_{n-1} =i_{n-1} , ..., X_1 = i_1, X_0 = i_0)
$$

c)
$$
= \mathbb{P}(X_0 = i_0) \mathbb{P}(X_1 = i_1 | X_0 = i_0) \mathbb{P}(X_2 = i_2 | X_1 = i_1) ... \mathbb{P}(X_n = i_n | X_{n-1} = i_{n-1})
$$

Answer (score 0):

This follows from several uses of the Markov property: $$p_k:=\mathbb P\left(X_k=i_k\mid X_{k-1}=i_{k-1},X_{k-2}=i_{k-2},X_0=i_0\right)=\mathbb P\left(X_k=i_k\mid X_{k-1}=i_{k-1}\right)$$
and the probability into question in b) is $$\mathbb P(X_0=i_0)\prod_{k=1}^np_k=\mathbb P(X_0=i_0)\prod_{k=1}^n\mathbb P\left(X_k=i_k\mid X_{k-1}=i_{k-1}\right).$$

Comment: For your last part, I can see the multiplication theorem $P(AB) = P(B | A)P(A)$ used on the LHS.  I was unsure if there was proof on why the LHS equals the RHS.

Answer (score 0):

By the definition of a Markov chain, the probability of the $k$ th state depends only on the $k-1$ th state, it is independent of the $k-2, k-3, \cdots, 0$ th states.

This can be explained best with the help of a state transition diagram.
For example, in [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tiQ0G.gif) Markov chain, there are no arrows linking state $2$ to state $0$, without passing through state $1$. As the diagram clearly shows, the $k$ th state is linked to the $k-1$ th state only. Hence, $$\mathbb{P}(X_k = i_k|X_{k-1}=i_{k-1}, \ldots, X_0=i_0) = \mathbb{P}(X_k = i_k | X_{k-1} = i_{k-1})$$